# updating an html textarea control from within java class

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-tool-suite

novice at web applications so trying to create a form based web application with REST capabilities. So basically I prompt the user to enter credentials and queries and make REST API requests on their behalf and based on success it should deliver the appropriate response to TextArea control on a html page. I am not sure how to do this based on the tutorial code I am using.

Here is the html page for the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
<title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>RESULT</h1>
<br/>
<p><label for="response">RESPONSE:</label></p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="response" name="${result.response}
 ">   </textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<a href="/greeting">SUBMIT A NEW REQUEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that I thought would handle the addition of the response to the object class created for the response;

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);

    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    sb.append(uid + "   " + nameType + "    " + custKey + 
    "       " +  "SUCCESSFULLY ADDED!");
    ResponseMsg = sb.toString();
    result.setResult(ResponseMsg);
```

the response class object:

```
public class result implements Serializable
{
@Autowired
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("response")  

private String result;
private String message;
private String error;
private String response;

public String getId() {
    return message;
}

public void setId(String response) {
    this.message = response;
}

public String getPayLoad() {
    return error;
}

public void setPayLoad(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}
public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
    }   

}
```

Hope this makes sense. I had other examples to try but had issues getting the server settings to work within Spring tool suite. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in general I would recommend to start with the guides at http://spring.io/guides. There are tons of examples and sample projects to start with as a newbie. And they can be used from within the Spring Tool Suite directly using the "Import Getting Started..." wizard.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and ran through errors that is still taking days to resolve. But yes I guess I should just stick with the tutorials.

Comment: what problems are you running into when using the guides within STS? If you download a fresh copy of the full STS distribution, starting with a fresh workspace, select the "Import Getting Started Content", select the "Rest Service" guide, for example, and press finish, you should end up with a nicely running project in your workspace. You can run it is "Run As Spring Boot..." and you should be ready to go. What is going wrong on that path?